# Trying to find the right event for when to dismiss a spinner in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, webview

I am using PKHUD to generate a spinner for loading so that the user knows the app is working correctly rather than just frozen.

I have to load other web pages as part of the app's functionality.

Preferably I'd have the spinner the entire time while the webpage loaded.

Currently I have the spinner working correctly, but it dismisses when the actual webview loads (so when the website starts loading) - I want that to happen when the website *finishes* loading.

Here's my code:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    HUD.show(.labeledProgress(title: "Loading Webview", subtitle: nil))
    self.navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(true, animated: true)
    userInfoUpdater.startPolling(closure: self.userUpdated(user:))
}

func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView : UIWebView) {
    HUD.hide()
}
```

So what event do I need to put HUD.hide() in? I'm relatively new to native iOS development so I'm not sure of what every potential event is.

Answer (score 0):

```
 func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView : UIWebView) {
     //Check here if still webview is loding the content
     if webView.isLoading {
        return
      }
     //executes after page finished loading
     NSLog(@"WebView loading finished");
     HUD.hide()
}
```

webViewDidFinishLoad fires multiple times, first when it renders the first frame and so on. `webView.isLoading` will become false when page is finished loading.

Comment: This leads to the HUD never hiding.

Comment: Code only answers are usually unhelpful for future viewers. As such, this answer would greatly benefit from an added explanation.

Comment: Also I should point out, I am trying all this in the ViewController